# crop the particular portion of image in android after zoom in or zoom out

Tags: android

I want to crop the particular portion of image(gallery or camera image) after

zoom in or zoom out, just like this given image in android.i am new in android.please help me.thank you.

[image: cut the particular portion of image in android]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many libraries available now to do your requirement. You can use
https://github.com/albinmathew/PhotoCrop for cropping out a particular region as square or circle with zoom in/out feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at android.graphics.Bitmap, you can use the API below to crop bitmap. And you can study API createScaledBitmap() if you wish.

```
/**
 * Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source
 * bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may
 * have been made. It is initialized with the same density as the original
 * bitmap.
 *
 * @param source   The bitmap we are subsetting
 * @param x        The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
 * @param y        The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
 * @param width    The number of pixels in each row
 * @param height   The number of rows
 * @return A copy of a subset of the source bitmap or the source bitmap itself.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the x, y, width, height values are
 *         outside of the dimensions of the source bitmap, or width is <= 0,
 *         or height is <= 0
 */
public static Bitmap createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    return createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height, null, false);
}
```

Comment: please tell in some more details

Comment: createBitmap will get  a new bitmap from the srouce bitmap, the new bitmap will be a cropped one if you set the params x, y, width and height correctly.